# $\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx=\int\limits_0^{\theta(n)} f(x) dx+\int\limits_{1-\theta(n)}^1 f(x) dx $

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a positive and continuous function on the interval $[0, 1]$. It can be shown
that there exists, for every natural number $n$, a real number $\theta(n) \in [0, 1]$ such that

$$\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx=\int\limits_0^{\theta(n)} f(x) dx+\int\limits_{1-\theta(n)}^1 f(x) dx $$

What is
$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\theta(n)$?

Please give some hint?

Comment: There seem to be different answers for $f(x)=\sin^k(\pi x)$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$

Comment: should it be required that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mean value theorem for integrals, there exists $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that:
$$\int_0^{\theta(n)}f(x)dx=f(x_n)\theta(n)\ \ \ \ \ \ \  \int_{1-\theta(n)}^1=f(y_n)\theta(n)
\tag 1$$

now prove the following:

- $x_n\to 0$ and $y_n\to 1$ how : LHS tends to zero,hence RHS tends to zero and is a sum of positive terms because $f$ positive so every term tends to zero hence $\theta(n)\to 0$ and use $0\leq x_n\leq \theta(n)$ the same method for $y_n$.
- $f$ is continue replace the formulas $(1)$ in the original equality and prove that:
  $$n\theta(n)\to\frac{1}{f(1)+f(0)}\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx $$

the limit is $+\infty$ if $f(0)=f(1)=0$

Comment: Thank you so much @Elaqqad....:)